# how to increase the border of the icons in filling the icon colors in css

Tags: html, css, sass, border

In my application I have the svg font smiley icon in grey color filling and I changed it to white filling color as

**.html**

```
<i class="stl icon icon-smiley-face-1"  aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

and in css I have added styles as

**.css**

```
  padding: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    font-size:100px;
    display:block;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
```

Now my icon looks fine with white filling but it is in narrow border(in circle shape).
Now my requirement is to increase the border width(in circle shape)  .Can anyone help me on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Add border-width, border-style and border-color to your css:

```css
.stl {
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: yellow;  
    border-style: solid;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 100px;
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<i class="stl" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: Thanks @A.Mello added border:2px solid red but the border width is coming in half part of the circle only. Can you suggest me how to apply the border width for entire circle

Comment: In "Run code snippet" I see the border on entire circle.  Maybe another css class you are using is causing this behaviour.  Please check classes 'stl', 'icon' and 'icon-smiley-face-1'